# Custom Login Page through a List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-login-page

I have a requirement to develop a Custom Login Page in SharePoint 2010 which should authenticate thru a SharePoint list on same farm. So, I will create User List with password and store those data with admin rights.

The thing is; I have users with PCs and without PCs in my company, but I have a HR Helpdesk SharePoint solution which should use with all users in company. Also, HR is maintaining the Company Employee Directory.

So, what I am planning; we also have kiosk machine in my company and the users without PC, can access Helpdesk system thru Kiosk and using the custom login.

I will use same Employee Directory List and add additional fields to capture Password field, Personal Email and Login Type.

Below is the list structure to the employee list and custom login;

[image]

So, when User selects the Custom Login type from Login Screen, system will check from Employee List user’s Login type, if the Login Type is Windows, then user must login with Windows Authentication and will show thru a message (because there are cases users get promoted and get new PCs, so that time admin can change the Login type to Windows)

If the user login type is Custom, then system will authenticate thru this list with a valid Employee code and password.

Kindly let me know the above solution is feasible or not in SharePoint 2010? Or let me know the best approach to the above business case to follow;

I tried enabling FBA authentication and I found it is so complex to manage. I need a simple user maintenance page which should do by HR Team; Also, Trusted Identify Provide is very hard to manage. For me, I need to provide the solution, in a way that IT should not interact with supporting to the solution after project deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Just give all the users Windows accounts in Active Directory and let them log in to the Kiosk using them. It makes no difference whether or not they have their own PCs.

What you are proposing is a really bad idea from a security perspective. But even so it will never work.

Answer (score 0):

You can port this codeplex solution: https://splistmp.codeplex.com/ It uses a list to manage user accounts and I guess that's what you're asking for.

It was built for SharePoint 2007 but with a bit of work you can get it to work in 2010 and 2013.

**HOWEVER**: Derek's suggestion of giving AD accounts for the users is the best solution for your problem. I've found membership providers to be very high maintenance.

The behaviour when you have a Membership Provider installed is that SharePoint asks which provider you want to use to Login and then it redirects the user to the login page he requested - I know this description to be valid with SP2013 and I think it's valid for 2010 as well.

To install your ported Membership Provider you'll need to add the MembershipProvider keys to the web.config of the Web Application where users will login, the web.config file for your SecurityToken Service and the web.config file for your central administration. (the Security Token Service wasn't a thing in SP 2007)